# Are breakers polarized?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I would like to know if a circuit breaker is polarized if it looks like this:

[image]

I would also like to know how I can manually turn off these breakers and how to reset them.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I cannot locate the datasheet for this thing.  I got it off amazon a couple days ago and it doesn't say anything. I'm going to retake the picture though. thank you!

Comment: google `gloso t3`

Comment: ok thank you very much! found what I need.